# Ionic dev build slow

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I just installed Ionic latest version (RC 0) and im using the CLI they have (latest version) - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli

They currently have a problem with slow builds when you are in development mode. To the question, is there possible to install a earlier version to skip this problem?

Greetings
xatroN

Comment: Might be the same problem as I have see https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-run-android-build-too-slow-for-cordova-testing-on-device/67003